# Retrieving a Skype recording that's more than a month old

Tags: skype, skype-for-windows-10

I lost a recording of a Skype call that was recorded back in January. Is there any way of retrieving that recording from Skype as it's 30 days already and I'm unable to access it anyway.

Comment: Where was it stored previously? Was it just in the app? Was it in the cloud? Did you download it to your computer?

Comment: It was just in the app, couldnt download or put in up in the cloud.. :(